# How do I change the From: address used for git format-patch?

Tags: git

I'm generating some patches for an opensource project and my From: line is always me@domain.com. I've been manually editing the From: line to be me-emaillist@domain.com before running git send-email.

1. Is there anyway to automatically do this?
2. Should I be doing this at all? I'm already using the envelope sender config.
3. Will the author line in the upstream repo be "me-emaillist@domain.com" because I changed the From address?

Example:

```
From fab0cf45f10686688a8138f60a09505200cbb2a4 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: John Doe <me-emaillist@domain.com>
Date: Mon, 25 Feb 2013 23:06:23 -0500
Subject: [PATCH] nand: adjust erase/read/write partition/chip size for bad blocks
```

After considering mvp's answer, my explicit answers are:

1. No, because...
2. No, because...
3. Yes, the From: line is taken from the Author of the commit because `git am` uses the From: line when setting the name of the author in the upstream repository.

Comment: You now can do a `git format-patch --from[=whom]`! See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17693171/6309)

Comment: And you can now (Git 2.10, Q3 2016) do a `git config format.from xxx`, to quickly fix the default sender for any patch creation. See [my (updated) answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17693171/6309)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting your git identity should be enough:

```
git config --global user.email me@domain.com
git config --global user.name "John Doe"
```

You can also set your identity per git repository: run these commands inside that git repostory and simply omit `--global` flag.

You probably should not use `me-emaillist@domain.com` because if someone `git am` it, this commit will have not your identity.

Probably the only reason to do that is to avoid spam to your primary address - but I think you will get it anyway as soon as it becomes public.

Comment: didn't work, I guess it always uses the Author of the commit being used for the patch.

Comment: I guess the answer to (3) above is that the Author line is taken from that From line. I had never used or read the man page for `git am`.

Comment: You are right - it is taken from actual commit when you use `git format-patch`. But if you have proper identity set using `git config`, that will be it.

Comment: Actually, what you said is not correct. `git config` only controls the author used for creating new commits whereas `git format-patch` uses whatever the author is set to in the metadata for the commit. The two are not really related. That is what caught me offguard. I think the problem is actually with the format-patch documentation. It and `am` are complimentary, but as stated before, only `am` explains how the patches from `format-patch` are interpreted.

Answer (score 3):

With [git1.8.4 (July 2013)](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.4.txt), you now can set that "From field":

> "`git format-patch`" learned "`--from[=whom]`" option, which sets the "`From:` " header to the specified person (or the person who runs the command, if "`=whom`" part is missing) and move the original author information to an in-body `From:` header as necessary.

See [commit a90804752f6ab2b911882d47fafb6c2b78f447c3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a90804752f6ab2b911882d47fafb6c2b78f447c3):

> `format-patch` generates emails with the "`From`" address set to the author of each patch. If you are going to send the emails, however, you would want to replace the author identity with yours (if they are not the same), and bump the author identity to an in-body
> header.
>
> Normally this is handled by `git-send-email`, which does the transformation before sending out the emails. However, some workflows may not use send-email (e.g., imap-send, or a custom script which feeds the mbox to a non-git MUA). They could each implement this feature themselves, but getting it right is non-trivial (one must canonicalize the identities by reversing any RFC2047 encoding or RFC822 quoting of the headers, which has caused many bugs in send-email over the years).
>
> This patch takes a different approach: it teaches format-patch a "`--from`" option which handles the ident check and in-body header while it is writing out the email.
> It's much simpler to do at this level (because we haven't done any quoting yet), and any workflow based on format-patch can easily turn it on.
>
> Signed-off-by: Jeff King `<peff@peff.net>`

You now can do a:

```
git format-path --from=...
```

With:

```
--from::
--from=<ident>::
```

> Use `ident` in the `From:` header of each commit email.
> If the author ident of the commit is not textually identical to the provided `ident`, place a `From:` header in the body of the message with the original author.
> If no `ident` is given, use the committer ident.
>
> **Note that this option is only useful if you are actually sending the emails and want to identify yourself as the sender, but retain the original author** (and `git am` will correctly pick up the in-body header).
> **Note also that `git send-email` already handles this transformation for you, and this option should not be used if you are feeding the result to `git send-email`**.

---

Update August 2016 (3 years later)

See [commit 6bc6b6c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6bc6b6c0dc0a58874a7a6b9afc3156a5cf9bb10d) (01 Aug 2016) by [Josh Triplett (`joshtriplett`)](https://github.com/joshtriplett).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit db40a62](https://github.com/git/git/commit/db40a622395397c84c247d343ef62acc8775d6b2), 10 Aug 2016)</sup>

> ### `format-patch`: `format.from` gives the default for `--from`

> This helps users who would prefer format-patch to default to `--from`,
> and makes it easier to change the default in the future.

[`git config` man page now includes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6bc6b6c0dc0a58874a7a6b9afc3156a5cf9bb10d/Documentation/config.txt#L1230-L1238):

> ### `format.from`:
>
> Provides the default value for the `--from` option to format-patch.
> Accepts a boolean value, or a name and email address.
>
> - If `false`, `format-patch` defaults to `--no-from`, using commit authors directly in the "From:" field of patch mails.
> - If `true`, `format-patch` defaults to `--from`, using your committer identity in the "`From:`" field of patch mails and including a "`From:`" field in the body of the patch mail if different.
> - If set to a non-boolean value, format-patch uses that value instead of your committer identity.
>
> Defaults to `false`.

---

Note that, with Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), spaces are better managed.

See [commit f696a2b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f696a2b1c850c81130740945835beec72727debf), [commit ffbea18](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ffbea1816dcbce12d4ffb304ddf8993ef611d4f1), [commit f447d02](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f447d0293e803d9acf390bbdf373ed98bdc125f4), [commit b6537d8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b6537d83ee30693efb17a35321b8bd03b752033a) (11 Feb 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d880c3d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d880c3de231da4ff930d12e07b3cae9dc0c31415), 17 Feb 2020)</sup>

> ### [`mailinfo`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ffbea1816dcbce12d4ffb304ddf8993ef611d4f1): be more liberal with header whitespace
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> RFC822 and friends allow arbitrary whitespace after the colon of a header and before the values.
> I.e.:
>
> ```
> Subject:foo
> Subject: foo
> Subject:  foo
> ```
>
> all have the subject "`foo`". But `mailinfo` requires exactly one space.
> This doesn't seem to be bothering anybody, but it is pickier than the standard specifies. And we can easily just soak up arbitrary whitespace there in our parser, so let's do so.
>
> Note that the test covers both too little and too much whitespace, but the "too much" case already works fine (because we later eat leading and trailing whitespace from the values).

---

With Git 2.38 (Q3 2022), "[`git format-patch --from=<ident>`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0e2a4764edea38c4aad95af246d6a7648a7d5e2d/Documentation/git-format-patch.txt#L264)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch#Documentation/git-format-patch.txt---fromltidentgt))</sup> can be told to add an in-body `From:` line even for commits that are authored by the given `<ident>` with `--force-in-body-from`"option.

See [commit d5fc07d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d5fc07df688ace8c5a32f66b358ebd55cdaf4d28), [commit 34bc1b1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/34bc1b1045af6ad813f4de662a453b3c77ba65a7), [commit b84d013](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b84d01393679d0e09d6fd198e771f2d1f5563986) (29 Aug 2022) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0e2a476](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0e2a4764edea38c4aad95af246d6a7648a7d5e2d), 09 Sep 2022)</sup>

> ### [`format-patch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/34bc1b1045af6ad813f4de662a453b3c77ba65a7): allow forcing the use of in-body `From:` header

> Users may be authoring and committing their commits under the same e-mail address they use to send their patches from, in which case they shouldn't need to use the in-body `From:` line in their outgoing e-mails.
> At the receiving end, "[`git am`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/34bc1b1045af6ad813f4de662a453b3c77ba65a7/Documentation/git-am.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am))</sup> will use the address on the `From:` header of the incoming e-mail and all should be well.
>
> Some mailing lists, however, mangle the From: address from what the original sender had; in such a situation, the user may want to add the in-body "`From:`" header even for their own patches.
>
> git format-patch --[no-]force-in-body-from` was invented for such users.

`git format-patch` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/34bc1b1045af6ad813f4de662a453b3c77ba65a7/Documentation/git-format-patch.txt#L278-L286):

> ### `--[no-]force-in-body-from`
>
> With the e-mail sender specified via the `--from` option, by
> default, an in-body "From:" to identify the real author of
> the commit is added at the top of the commit log message if
> the sender is different from the author.
>
> With this option,
> the in-body "`From:`" is added even when the sender and the
> author have the same name and address, which may help if the
> mailing list software mangles the sender's identity.

Comment: See also [commit 2d9396c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2d9396c2feac8b707b367c64cd59604d7bc86a33) from Git 2.44 (Q1 2024): When processing "From" headers in an email, mailinfo "unquotes" quoted
strings and rfc822 parenthesized comments: `From: "A U Thor" <someone@example.com>` becomes `Author: A U Thor\nEmail: someone@example.com`

Answer (score 0):

Try running `echo 'alias me "John Doe <me-emaillist@domain.com"' >> ~/.gitaliases`.

Comment: didn't work, I guess it always uses the Author of the commit being used for the patch.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to use a specific email address instead of another is to use **sendmail email aliases format**, now supported by [`git send-email`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-email) (at least in Git 2.5+, July 2015)

See [commit 3169e06](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3169e06daf297227362fb64a9d5c2cc451fefcbb) (26 May 2015) by [Allen Hubbe (`allenbh`)](https://github.com/allenbh).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 412e63f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/412e63f0fd683addc380f9c65d05306bd2027039), 16 Jun 2015)</sup>

> ### `send-email`: add `sendmail` email aliases format
>
> Teach send-email to read aliases in the `sendmail` aliases format, i.e.

```
<alias>: <address|alias>[, <address|alias>...]
```

> Examples:

```
alice: Alice W Land <awol@example.com>
bob: Robert Bobbyton <bob@example.com>
# this is a comment
   # this is also a comment
chloe: chloe@example.com
abgroup: alice, bob
bcgrp: bob, chloe, Other <o@example.com>
```

Notes:

> - Quoted aliases and quoted addresses are not supported.
> - Line continuations are not supported.

---

For Git 2.6+ (Q3 2015), [Remi Lespinet (`Awaryn`)](https://github.com/Awaryn) did a *huge* rework on that feature:

> "`git send-email`" now performs alias-expansion on names that are given via `--cccmd`, etc.
>
> This round comes with a lot more enhanced e-mail address parser.

See [commit fa5b1aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa5b1aa9a1e1f0ad7b2728bec3712d3fab5fe734), [commit b1c8a11](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b1c8a11c8024c88346a06274f87a0605afd4a53b), [commit 1fe9703](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1fe9703f08cfac8bd2db7a17bb6f3a61cf20ef35), [commit c46e27a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c46e27aa774eae2ac58f1763afe00108f3a1e5d3), [commit 193d716](https://github.com/git/git/commit/193d7160111ebf5b898f53240c33c1e4101d9598), [commit b5e112d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5e112d8d240b299553f17c8e476ef16fca4001f), [commit d4cf11c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d4cf11c2e948890c2daf27fba6727e3b814cfe3c), [commit f6f79e5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f6f79e5ee3d0b0fa1d2084bae31f8ea8e7d5c3f8), [commit 62089fb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/62089fb8e9863b93cc7d9280ec39818dc28c23bf),    (30 Jun 2015), [commit b1c8a11](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b1c8a11c8024c88346a06274f87a0605afd4a53b),  (30 Jun 2015),  (30 Jun 2015), [commit 8d314d7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d314d7afec5adaaa8e22332e39fe84a39584653) (07 Jul 2015) by [Remi Lespinet (`Awaryn`)](https://github.com/Awaryn).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8f50e2e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8f50e2eef794bf8be4705738756c00c39042db03), 03 Aug 2015)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

For me (git version 2.17.1) this worked:

`git config format.from true`

According to `man git config`:

> ... If true, format-patch defaults to --from, using your
>   committer identity in the "From:" field of patch mails and including a "From:" field in the body of the patch mail if different.